# The skin of programmers.stackexchange.com. Visited/unvisited links. Is it going to be changed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Hi,

I found out that my eyes get tired when I spend more then 10 minutes on [the site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and this is because of the small difference between the colors used for visited/unvisited posts:

[image: unvisited]

[image: visited]

Is this going to be changed?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry, if this is not the right place for this question, or if inappropriately tagged.

Comment: With new skin the problem persists. @Jin could take care about this issue?

Comment: I have made the visited links much darker. The change will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. Pr.SE is near to earn your own theme.